# AWS CLI - How to include sensitive information in 'Systems Manager Run Command'?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Is there a way I can send sensitive information (e.g. password) as part of the 'Run Command' under EC2 Systems Manager Services?

Because the way I see it, everytime I run a command against an instance, that command gets logged and is visible from the web console - the command can be viewed.

*OR*

is there way to pull sensitive information within Run command's command from parameter store and not have that value (sensitive info) echoed to the web console?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at the Parameter Store feature of Systems Manager. This lets you define parameters, including Secure String parameter values that can be encrypted using a KMS key of your choice. This will take care of sensitive parameters:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html

/Mats